# 3 columns overlapping the footer on mobile browser

Tags: html, css

**Footer is on right place but the columns in section are overlapping the footer**

```
.columns {
float:left;   
    width: 22%;
    height: 30%;
margin-left:8%;
}
```

> Instead of float:left; I have used display:inline-block;  but issue
>   not resolved this problem is occurring when website displayed on
>   mobile. When viewed on desktop it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS
 box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 5%;
}

.column1 {
  background: #b40404;
  padding: 5%;
  color: #fff;
}

.column2 {
  background: #000;
  padding: 5%;
  color: #fff;
}

.column3 {
  background: #b40404;
  padding: 5%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="column1">
        This is column 1<br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vero labore obcaecati illum reprehenderit incidunt consequatur quidem, id repellendus impedit, quaerat, mollitia ea culpa sint? Totam sunt omnis quis
        eaque.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="column2">
        This is column 2<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium mollitia, incidunt accusantium iure eius suscipit fugit tempore veniam deleniti, nulla dolore repudiandae voluptas, eaque architecto ratione recusandae
        consectetur officia. Saepe.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="column3">
        This is column 3<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vitae nulla, beatae tenetur ea eaque obcaecati perspiciatis, architecto nemo culpa id non facilis distinctio aliquam. Accusamus voluptatum mollitia perferendis
        libero.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use Bootstrap. Use the class container then row and define columns inside it. Like this:

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I'll try this then comment

Comment: if you want responsive, you can go with it. It would be the best option. Here is the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/dpshrays/pen/GdrMbp#code-area

If non responsive also work, then you can use this codepen:

https://codepen.io/dpshrays/pen/aGpLRa

Comment: I'm using this code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_pricing_table it is responsive but why t is overlapping the footer? On desktop it's displaying ok but on mobile it overlaps

Comment: what shall be add in this so it won't overlap? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_pricing_table

Comment: Adding the Media Query will solve it

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

Have you written this Media Query? Change it according to the screen size. Also, for mobile display, i would suggest, use the code above.

Comment: Can I have your fb or else where I can message you later?